# pd.get_dummies One-Hot Encoding but Keep the Order of Appearence

Tags: pandas, data, data-cleaning

So I have this data which which has the 12 months as below:
[image]

When I one-hot encode it using `pd.get_dummies` the result is this:
[image]
You see that the new columns are ordered alphabetically losing the months order, which makes reading the data hard. Is there any way to preserve the order?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a separate dataframe with the dummy variables, reorder it, and concat it with the original dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'jan', 'march', 'jan']})
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.month)
dummies = dummies[['jan', 'feb', 'march']]
pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
```

[image]